# Creating a percentage in SQL Server using a counter

Tags: sql-server, count, distinct, percentage

Suppose you have this data in the table 'Student':

```
ID     COUNTY
------------------
1      Millwood
2      Jackson
3      Kendall
4      Millwood
5      Worth
6      Belton
7      Belton
8      Worth
9      Jackson
10     Millwood
11     Kendall
12     Worth
13     Belton
14     Belton
15     Maxwell
16     Maxwell
17     Maxwell
18     Maxwell
19     Maxwell
20     Johnson
```

Millwood has 3 people, Jackson has 2, Kendall has 2, Worth has 3, Belton has 4, Maxwell has 5, and Johnson has 1. Let's say I want the top 5 counties with the greatest population.  That would be:

```
Maxwell   5
Belton    4
Worth     3
Millwood  3
Jackson   2
Kendall   2
```

Now, let's say I want an output with a percentage of the total population.  By this data, there are 20 total people among those six counties (an entire state).  Maxwell has 25% of the population, Belton has 20%, Worth and Millwood have 15% each, and Jackson and Kendall have 10% each.  How would I get that output in SQL Server?

```
Maxwell   25%
Belton    20%
Worth     15%
Millwood  15%
Jackson   10%
Kendall   10%
```

I have to link two tables to get a county name.  This code below has not worked:

```
SELECT 
    countycodes.countyname, 
    SUM(student.mstid) AS tot_stdts_by_county, 
    ROUND(SUM(student.mstid) / SUM(SUM(student.mstid)) OVER (), 2) * 100 AS pct
FROM 
    Student 
INNER JOIN 
    CountyCodes ON Student.MCOUNTY = CountyCodes.CountyCode 
                AND Student.MSTATE = CountyCodes.StateCode
WHERE 
    (Student.MSTLEV IN (1, 2, 3, 4))
GROUP BY 
    Student.MRPTYR, Student.MRPTTRM, CountyCodes.CountyCode, 
    Student.MCOUNTY, Student.MENTST, CountyCodes.CountyName, 
    Student.MSTATE, CountyCodes.StateCode
HAVING 
    (Student.MRPTTRM = 'sa') 
    AND (Student.MRPTYR = 2007) 
    AND (Student.MENTST = 'ZY')
ORDER BY 
    tot_stdts_by_county DESC
```

Comment: `HAVING` should only be applied to **aggregations** of columns - e.g. `HAVING SUM(...) > 100` or so. Your "simple" expressions here should be part of the `WHERE` clause instead.....

Comment: What "doesn't work" about `sum / sum(sum) over...`?

Comment: If you move the predicates from the having clause to the where clause then you do not need to GROUP BY all those fields as they are not being used "unaggregated" in the where clause, only the student.mstid is needed in grouping. After that, you can simply flip your percentage calculation around to be something like COUNT(student.mstid) / CAST(SUM(COUNT(student.mstid))OVER() AS FLOAT) * 100. You might want to add a divide by zero guard as well.

Comment: Ross Bush:  This is close, but...not quite.  I appreciate your help.  How should I prevent that mathematical undefined (dividing by 0) from happening?  I know it would be something about a null in there some way.

Comment: @JasonHead - One way to prevent divide by zero would be to add a CASE statement to your derived field and check if the divisor=0 -> CASE X=0 THEN NULL(or 0) ELSE Y/X END. If you calculate an aggregate once then there is not a penalty for it appearing many other times in the same scope, at least using sql server.

Comment: @JasonHead - How does a SUM against your ID field give you a valid argument in calculating percentage? What if the ID's where 155555678, 1555555679, etc?

Comment: @JasonHead I think you are looking for a COUNT() / SUM(COUNT() OVER(<each aggregate>)) <- That would yield, Group Count /  Total overall Count, for each record.

Comment: It WAS on target.  My own where clause was not correct, giving a larger denominator than necessary.  I also figured a way to round it to two decimal places.  THANK YOU!